# iPhone how to compress the files while upload to server?

Tags: iphone, ios

What is the best way to compress and upload file from iPhone? Am using ASIHTTP to upload the file to my server. But am getting network error while upload the large files to server. So how to compress and upload it using ASIHTTP?

```
Code:
[serverUploadRequest setPostValue:withEmail_id forKey:@"mail_id"];
    [serverUploadRequest setPostValue:withPassword forKey:@"pwd"];
    [serverUploadRequest setPostValue:withFileName forKey:@"file_name"];
    [serverUploadRequest setPostValue:withFileExtension forKey:@"file_extension"];
[serverUploadRequest setData:fileData withFileName:withFileName andContentType:@"application/octet-stream" forKey:@"userfile"];

[serverUploadRequest startSynchronous];
```

This is working fine but when i try to upload the large files some times am getting upload failed error. So is possible to compress and upload the file to server. Am using windows 2003 server with PHP

Thanks

Comment: Post code and error for better results

Comment: i want to upload the text files or pdf files.

Comment: can you post your web server log so we get an idea what kind of error you are getting (body too long...)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Objective-Zip](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/) to zip the file.

For more info about its usage, visit this [link](http://www.hindsightlabs.com/blog/2010/12/23/reading-and-writing-zip-files-on-the-iphone/)

Comment: all links broken. please fix or delete? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[May this link useful to you](http://www.flyblog.info/catprogramming/202.html)
You can zip file you files before uploading to server.

Answer (score 0):

easy & fast C based zip.
http://code.google.com/p/miniz/source/browse/trunk/miniz.c?r=31

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method I used for creating a zip to upload 3 image.

```
-(void)zipImage:(NSString *) filename: (NSString *) file1: (NSString *) file2: (NSString *) file3{

ZipArchive *zipfile = [[ZipArchive alloc]init];
[zipfile CreateZipFile2:filename];
[zipfile addFileToZip:file1 newname:@"C1.jpg"];
[zipfile addFileToZip:file2 newname:@"C2.jpg"];
[zipfile addFileToZip:file3 newname:@"T1.jpg"];
[zipfile CloseZipFile2];

}
```

The zip library is miniZip ( http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/ )

As you can see the initial call is to init the ZipArchive object, next create the zipfile, then just recursively call addFileToZip for each item you want in your file.

P.